# Expose a specific .net object as JSON

Tags: .net, web-services, json

I'm currently enabling JSON calls to my web services using the ScriptService attribute.  The problem is that one of my classes references a second class and .Net is not picking up and writing out the JavaScript for the second class.

As a workaround I can write a dummy method that just returns the second class.  Then .Net writes the JSON to allow it to be serialized.  So in the following example:

```
[ScriptService]
public class MyService : WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    public void SaveClass1(Class1 class1) {
        ...
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Class1 {
    public Class2 class2 { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Class2 {
}
```

MyService.asmx/js won't write code to allow me to instantiate Class2 in order for me to populate Class1.  But I can make it work if I add:

```
[WebMethod]
public Class2 Dummy() {
    return new Class2();
}
```

to MyService.  Any alternatives to my nasty workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [System.Web.Script.Services.GenerateScriptTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.generatescripttypeattribute.aspx), which specifies that a server type should be included in the generated proxy code. You can apply this attribute to the web service itself or any method marked with [WebMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.aspx).

For example:

```
[ScriptService]
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(Class2))]
public class MyService : WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    public void SaveClass1(Class1 class1) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lee, not sure if this works in your JSON/`[ScriptService]` scenario, but to serialize an object graph in [Searcharoo.net](http://searcharoo.net/) I used the `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude` attribute on the 'base' class that I needed to serialize.

Basically this tells the XmlSerializer about `Class2` so that it can be included in the `Class1` serialization... kinda like an "opt-in" strategy for handling deep hierachies of objects.

You would add it like this (in your example):

```
[Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(Class2))]
public class Class1 {
    public Class2 class2 { get; set; }
}
```

...and then this

```
[WebMethod]
public void SaveClass1(Class1 class1) {
    ...
}
```

should return JSON with `Class2` data inside `Class1`.

I did a quick google to find [troubleshooting...XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx) which might be a good read. HTH

Comment: XmlInclude is used to include derived types in WSDL service descriptions. In this question, Class2 is not derived from Class1 and the server generates JavaScript code not a WSDL service description. Use GenerateScriptTypeAttribute instead.