# ASP.NET ScriptService deserialization problem with derived types

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json, scriptservice

I have a `ScriptService` web method (.NET 3.5) which takes a single parameter of an abstract base type:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
[ScriptMethod()]
public bool Test(Item item) { ... }
```

And:

```
namespace Namespace {
public abstract class Item
{
    public int id;
}

public class Group : Item
{
    public Item[] items;
}

public class Instance : Item
{
    public string whatever;
}
}
```

Usually, when the method is called, `item` will be a `Group` which contains `Instance` and/or `Group` objects.  I'm calling this service from jQuery; I'm not using the Microsoft client-side framework.  Calls to other methods work fine.

**The problem:**  When I make the call, an exception is thrown before my method is even invoked.  For example, if my call is:

```
POST /WebService.asmx/Test HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*

{"item":{"id":0,"__type":"Namespace.Group","items":[]}}
```

...I get an `InvalidOperationException`:

```
{"Message":"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2 dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

If I drop the `__type` member of the JSON object or change it to `Namespace.Item` (and remove the `abstract` modifier from `Item`), the exception goes away, but the resulting deserialized object is obviously kinda useless.

What am I missing?

Comment: I got an error just like this but my was problem completely different. I converted a WCF service into an ASMX service. Each one uses a different format for the `__type` property. Updating `__type` to use ASMX's format completely resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ah ha!  Clicking around the related links on the right side of this question, I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451420/expose-a-specific-net-object-as-json/580906#580906) that helped me solve this problem.

The `GenerateScriptType` attribute must be applied to the web service class:

```
[WebService( ... )]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(Group))]
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(Instance))]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    [ScriptMethod()]
    public bool Test(Item item) { ... }
}
```

Without these attributes, the deserializer doesn't know about my derived types.

Comment: I had the same issue, but i do not use derived types. it was necessary becuase one of the viewmodels, used within another viewmodel is not in the same cs file.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this using `Newtonsofts JsonConvert` as below.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]      
public static void MyAjaxCallingMethod(object inputs)
    {           
    string stingDataFromAjaxCall = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inputs);
            MyObject myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(stingDataFromAjaxCall);
            ....}
```