# Can I send an object from client-side javascript to server-side code via ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Can I send an object from client-side javascript to server-side code via ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4):

In ASP.NET WebForms i would use a ScriptService:

Checkout this samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx

The `GenerateScriptType` attribute can used if you wanna pass/get hole objects to the service:
[ASP.NET ScriptService deserialization problem with derived types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819071/asp-net-scriptservice-deserialization-problem-with-derived-types)

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://msdnmagazine.com/ws")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(Object1))]
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(Object2))]
[ScriptService]
public class StockQuoteService : WebService
{
    static Random _rand = new Random(Environment.TickCount);

    [WebMethod]
    public int GetStockQuote(string symbol)
    {
        return _rand.Next(0, 120);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sample shows how to call a web service and pass a single value, however it does not show how to pass an object (including properties).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. One way could be, to use a web method; for instance:

1. Create a service
2. Call from the JavaScript method like: `DataService.Push(yourObject)`;

For instance:

**Javascript methods:**

```
function btnGenerate_onclick(result) {
    DataService.Push(getDataFromSomeDiv(), onGenerateReportComplete /*callback method*/);
    //or
    //DataService.Push(document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML, onGenerateReportComplete /*callback method*/);

}

function onGenerateReportComplete(result) {
            alert("Success:" + result);
}
```

**Service methods:**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class DataService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] //If you want?
    public bool Push(object someObject)
    {
        //var v = someObject as MyObjectClass;//Process object 
        return true;
    }
}
```

EDIT: **How would javascript know what is server-side DataService?**

This will require reference of web service in the markup. For instance like following:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server">
            <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="DataService.asmx" />
        </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Or you can use callbacks/[page methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page_methods.aspx).

Comment: You something missed. How would javascript know what is server-side DataService?

Answer (score 2):

Not as such. You can serialise the object to a string, send that string to ASP.NET and then convert it into an object again on the other side.

JSON is a good serialization format for this, and you can drop simple objects directly into the various libraries that are around for it (and that are [listed in the penultimate section of the JSON homepage](http://json.org/)).

For more complex objects, you will need to extract the relavent bits of data you need to recreate them before doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Ben Dotnet is right about using a **ScriptService** in asp.net WebForms. In addition to using the **ScriptService** decorator the **GenerateScriptType** decorator is important in order to make sure that the complex type you're wanting to use is included. I found the articles Ben linked to be useful in addition to this one: http://www.webreference.com/programming/asp-net-ajax/complex-data-types/index.html

Here is how I was able to do exactly what you're trying. First I defined the custom type I wanted to use in my code behind file.

```
namespace TestProject
{
    public class SampleData
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string StartDate { get; set; }
            public string EndDate { get; set; }

            public SampleData()
            { }
    }
    public partial class SamplePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        /* The rest of the SamplePage.aspx.cs file goes here */
    }
}
```

Then I created a WebMethod/ScriptMethod in my SamplePage code behind like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(SampleData))]
public static bool EditReminder(SampleData data)
{
    /* Server side code goes here */
    return true;
}
```

Then, on the client-side page I was able to create an object of type SampleData and pass that using the PageMethods like this. *Don't forget to include the namespace, this is necessary.*

```
function some_javascript_function () {
    var sample_data = new TestProject.SampleData()
    sample_data.id = 1;
    sample_data.StartDate = '6/24/1976';
    sample_data.EndDate = '3/20/2012';
    PageMethods.EditReminder(sample_data, OnEditReminderComplete)
}

function OnEditReminderComplete () {
    if (result) alert("Success!");
    else alert("Failure!");
}
```

Also, don't forget to include the script manager and enable page methods like this somewhere on your page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use Json and do POST. If you are using jQuery you can use $.ajax to post the values to server side. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please tell me more about Json (explain,example)?

Comment: This is a good reference point http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx